# Add EventListener to svg element is not a function

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I would listen to mouse event on svg elements to create a tooltip

First I import and initialise tooltip lib

```
import d3Tip from 'd3-tip';
...
( Inside component )
var svg = d3.select('#svg8727');
let tip = d3Tip();
tip.attr('class', 'd3-tip').html(function(d) {
  return `<strong>Frequency:</strong> <span style="color:red"> text</span>`;
});
svg.call(tip);
```

Then I select my elements and bind data.

```
let trainSelect = svg.selectAll('.train-w-dir').data(schedules, function(d: ISchedule) {
  if (d != undefined) {
  return d.train;
  }
});
```

I get an array of `EnterNode` elements here's each element format ( on debugger )

```
namespaceURI: "http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
ownerDocument: document
__data__: {remp_dest: null, cap: 922, tp_des_r: "00:20:44+00:00", dest: 271015, descentes: 0, …}
_next: null
_parent: svg#svg8727
```

then I add event listener to selectedElements

```
trainSelect
  .enter()
  .on('mouseover', tip.show)
  .on('mouseout', tip.hide);
```

I get the error

> core.js:9110 ERROR TypeError: this.addEventListener is not a function

I'm trying to implement tooltip as mentionned in [this github repo](https://github.com/caged/d3-tip)

Comment: can you share the code where you defined `tip` ?

Comment: I have added the code ( I'm using Angular )

Comment: Although your enter selection is not empty it does not contain real DOM elements but mere stubs as placeholders for the elements to be appended. You don't actually `.append()` any elements for the enter selection. From the docs: *"Returns the enter selection: placeholder nodes for each datum that had no corresponding DOM element in the selection."* As I mentioned in my answer to your [other question](/questions/58270789) you might need to rethink the way you bind the data and build the DOM. To an experienced D3 developer this looks somewhat odd.

Comment: OK I understand, but what I would like to do is not append a new element, but instead select and existing element on DOM to listen to. The elements to select have `id` attribute equal to the `__data__.train`, I don't know how to select them after `enter` and before `on` instantiation

Comment: I assume that my problem now is not anymore the same as the main question so here's a new post https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58273179/d3js-data-binding-enter-then-select-an-element-to-listen-to