# d3js data binding enter then select an element to listen to

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I would like to select elements from DOM and listen to mouse event when hover them.

I'm using [this library](https://github.com/caged/d3-tip) ( example on link )

```
let trainSelect = svg.selectAll('.train-w-dir').data(schedules, function(d: ISchedule) {
    if (d != undefined) {
        return d.train;
    }
});
trainSelect
    .enter()
    .select(/ELEMENT TO SELECT/) // instead of append a new dom element as in the example
    .on('mouseover', tip.show)
    .on('mouseout', tip.hide);
```

What I would like to is to select a DOM element that have `id` attribute equal to every `trainSelect` array (EnterNode or placeholder ?) `data.train` field. Because I don't need to append a new element, but just listen to existing elements

Here the format of `trainSelect` items

```
namespaceURI: "http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
ownerDocument: document
__data__: {remp_dest: null, cap: 922, tp_des_r: "00:20:44+00:00", dest: 271015, descentes: 0, …}
_next: null
_parent: svg#svg8727
```

**UPDATE**
I tried to make selection like this 
trainSelect

```
.enter()
.each(elm => {
   return d3.select(`#${elm.train}`);
})
.on('mouseover', tip.show)
.on('mouseout', tip.hide);
```

But I get this error

> ERROR DOMException: Failed to execute 'querySelector' on 'Document': '#123596' is not a valid selector.

Comment: This clearly is an [*XY-problem*](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). Like I already mentioned on your other two questions: you are trying to fix a crooked solution which you think should fix your problem. I strongly suggest you clean up your questions and post a new one describing your problem or what you are trying to achieve instead of messing around with this approach. Also, try setting up a [mcve], i.e. an executable demo to play around with. I am sure it won't be long before you get a decent answer on that.

Comment: here's my question with a demo https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58277723/show-tooltip-on-hover-using-d3-tip-js

Answer (score -1):

The problem stems from your IDs starting with a number. This makes it harder to locator with a CSS selector or when using `querySelector`

You would need to escape each character likes this:

```
document.querySelector("#\\31\\32\\33\\35\\39\\36")
```

Which is really ugly and not very usable. I would recommend appending a letter to the start of your IDs. Then you can find the elements normally without the need for escaping.